# Use Linq to find records with missing related data

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I am trying to use Linq to Entities to find the categories where no orders exist.

```
 TABLE Customer              TABLE Order
------------------         ----------------
CustId   Category          OrderId FKCustId
  1         2                 1       1
  2         2
  3         3
```

This is a classic 1 to many Customer/Order relationship. Given this data, only category 3 has no orders associated with it, so I want to generate a result set with category 3 as the only item. This must be a straightforward query to write, but I have not been able to figure it out. I've tried a ton of different angles; here is one that didn't work:

```
var dtos = ctx.Customers
       .GroupBy(c => c.Category)
       .Where(c => !c.Any(c2 => !c2.Orders.Any()))
       .Select(c => c.Key);
```

When I tried this, it returned a category that *does* have orders while not returning the category missing orders.

Thanks in advance for any help!
Roger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is close, but the `!Any` followed by `!Any` is throwing off your logic. You want to select categories where all customers have no orders. But your query selects all categories where no customer has no order. <kbd>I hope that made sense</kbd>

Try changing your first `!Any` to `All`:

```
var dtos = ctx.Customers
   .GroupBy(c => c.Category)
   .Where(c => c.All(c2 => !c2.Orders.Any()))
   .Select(c => c.Key);
```

or in query syntax:

```
var dtos = 
    from c in Customers
    group c by c.Category into g
    where g.All(c => !c.Orders.Any())
    select g.Key;
```

---

Alternatively change the second `!Any` to `Any`.

```
var dtos = ctx.Customers
   .GroupBy(c => c.Category)
   .Where(c => !c.Any(c2 => c2.Orders.Any()))
   .Select(c => c.Key);
```

or in query syntax:

```
var dtos = 
    from c in Customers
    group c by c.Category into g
    where !g.Any(c => c.Orders.Any())
    select g.Key;
```

Comment: Changing !Any to All got things working. Can't believe I was so close - thanks for getting me the rest of the way there.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to get the customers who do not have any orders and then get the categories. Sort of do your where first and then get categories out

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion but I don't think this would work. Getting customers without orders would return cust ID #2 who belongs to category 2, but we don't want this category in the result set.

Comment: @user591281 - I am confused. Looking at the sample data you provided, cat2 is valid in resultset too because it doesn't have any orders right?

Comment: Cat 2 is not valid because cust 1, who belongs to cat 2, has an order, and I want only those categories where no orders exist, regardless of customer. Hope that makes sense.